Constructor invocation syntax in PowerShell 4.0 and lower without using New-Object
I ran across some older code today that piqued my curiosity.  I'm aware of 2x different syntactical ways of instantiating .NET objects in PowerShell 4.0
# Using New-Object to pass multiple args to the constructor
$ex = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileNotFoundException -ArgumentList 'No File Found!', 'C:\NoFile.txt'


# Alternate Syntax - how can you pass multiple args?
$ex = [System.IO.FileNotFoundException] 'No File Found!'


[EDIT] -- NOTES MOTIVATED BY COMMENTS

The class keyword (and support for classes) was introduced with PowerShell 5.0 back in 2016.
PowerShell 5.0 also (finally) exposed the native .NET class constructor methods.
In terms of instantiating objects, the New-Object cmdlet has since fallen out of preferential favor with newer versions of PowerShell -- and continues to see little use today, with the exception of implementing backwards compatability (e.g. PowerShell 4.0) and authoring scripts/functions/modules that support multiple OS/PowerShell generations.


Questions:

Where is this alternate syntax documented?  I haven't yet found anything online in terms of official documentation.
How can you pass multiple arguments using this alternate syntax and call a specific constructor overload?
Is there a name for this alternate syntax?


Does [System.IO.FileNotFoundException] 'No File Found!' even work in pwsh 4?

@santiago-squarzon "Does [System.IO.FileNotFoundException] 'No File Found!' even work in pwsh 4?"   Yes, it does.  It actually works in PS 2.0 as well.

There is also [SomeClassName]::new(param1, param2, param3)

I think it is called literal initializer and I wouldn't call it "Alternate Syntax", it is more the "New Syntax", knowing that it exists since PowerShell V3.0 (12 years ago), Besides, the New-Object cmdlet is sometimes even called legacy. Personally I think creating a new instance using the New-Object should be avoided by now (meaning: if you aren't in clear need of those PowerShell legacy versions).

@Charlieface that syntax was added in pwsh 5.1 didnt exist in 4 but probably should add that info to my answer

@SantiagoSquarzon I think it was actually 5.0, anyway every supported version of Windows has 5.1, so not sure what OP's system is. Great answer by the way.

@Charlieface thanks :) yes you're right that one was 5.0

Paul π: I've added a last clarification that is somewhat obscure on how you could make casting work for multiple overloads however I'm honestly not sure if that could work in PowerShell 4.

I'll update the question with these comments in mind.

something to consider unrelated to the question but the PowerShell ::new and the C# new aren't exactly the same. ::new is purely based on reflection (LINQ expressions), PowerShell in itself is a masterclass on reflection.


Where is this alternate syntax documented?
In 6.18 .NET Conversion, you can create an object by casting when one of the conversion rules are met. A few of them, the most commonly known:

Constructors: If the destination type has a constructor taking a single argument whose type is that of the source type, that constructor is called to perform the conversion.
class Foo {
    [string] $FooProp

    Foo([string] $foo) {
        $this.FooProp = $foo
    }
}

[Foo] 'OK!'


Parse Method: If the source type is string and the destination type has a method called Parse, that method is called to perform the conversion.
class Foo {
    [string] $FooProp

    static [Foo] Parse([string] $foo) {
        return [Foo]@{ FooProp = $foo }
    }
}

[Foo] 'OK!'


Explicit Cast Operator: If the source type has an explicit cast operator that converts to the destination type, that operator is called to perform the conversion. If the destination type has an explicit cast operator that converts from the source type, that operator is called to perform the conversion.
class Foo {
    [string] $FooProp

    static [Foo] op_Explicit([string] $foo) {
        return [Foo]@{ FooProp = $foo }
    }
}

[Foo] 'OK!'



How can you pass multiple arguments using this alternate syntax and call a specific constructor overload?
You cannot as-is, you can work your way around it using a PSTypeConverter, see bottom section of this answer for details.
The closer could be in 5.1 when they would allow you to instantiate using a hashtable literal:
class Foo {
    [string] $FooProp
    [string] $BarProp
}

[Foo]@{ FooProp = 'OK!'; BarProp = '123' }

And, this one added in 5.0, the ::new intrinsic member:
class Foo {
    [string] $FooProp
    [string] $BarProp

    Foo([string] $foo, [string] $bar) {
        $this.FooProp, $this.BarProp = $foo, $bar
    }
}

[Foo]::new('OK!', '123')

Or perhaps reflection (not even close to what you're looking for, also not even sure if this works in 4.0).
[Foo].GetConstructor(@([string], [string])).Invoke(@('OK!', '123'))


Using a PSTypeAdapter as workaround
This simplified example demos how you can use a PSTypeAdapter to cast from object[] to StreamReader targeting the StreamReader(String, Encoding) overload. Source value type could be different from object[], for example you could use cast from hash table.
In this case, I'm not sure if this could work and how you could make this work in PowerShell 4.0, PowerShell classes where only made available in PowerShell 5.1. Perhaps a compiled class could work.

First define a class that inherits from PSTypeAdapter:

class StreamReaderConverter : System.Management.Automation.PSTypeConverter
{
    [bool] CanConvertFrom([Object] $sourceValue, [type] $destinationType)
    {
        if ($destinationType -ne [System.IO.StreamReader]) {
            return $false
        }

        if ($sourceValue -isnot [array] -or $sourceValue.Count -ne 2) {
            return $false
        }

        $path, $enc = $sourceValue
        if ($enc -isnot [System.Text.Encoding] -or $path -isnot [string]) {
            return $false
        }

        return $true
    }

    [Object] ConvertFrom(
        [Object] $sourceValue,
        [type] $destinationType,
        [System.IFormatProvider] $formatProvider,
        [bool] $ignoreCase)
    {
        $file = Get-Item $sourceValue[0] -ErrorAction Ignore
        if (-not $file -or $file -isnot [System.IO.FileInfo])
        {
            throw [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException]::new(
                "Cannot find path '$($sourceValue[0])' because it does not exist or is not a file.")
        }

        # targets `public StreamReader(string path, Encoding encoding);` overload
        return [System.IO.StreamReader]::new(
            $file.FullName,
            [System.Text.Encoding] $sourceValue[1])
    }

    [bool] CanConvertTo([Object] $sourceValue, [type] $destinationType)
    {
        return $this.CanConvertFrom($sourceValue, $destinationType)
    }

    [Object] ConvertTo(
        [Object] $sourceValue,
        [type] $destinationType,
        [System.IFormatProvider] $formatProvider,
        [bool] $ignoreCase)
    {
        return $this.ConvertFrom(
            $sourceValue, $destinationType, $formatProvider, $ignoreCase)
    }
}


Then Update-TypeData using this new type as the -TypeConverter parameter:

$updateTypeDataSplat = @{
    TypeName      = [System.IO.StreamReader]
    TypeConverter = [StreamReaderConverter]
}
Update-TypeData @updateTypeDataSplat


Lastly, test:

$reader = [System.IO.StreamReader] ('.\myFile.txt', [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII)
$reader.CurrentEncoding # should be ASCII

In PowerShell 4 you might be able to define your own type via Add-Type I'm not sure what C# version it supports though, the following should work fine in PowerShell 5.1.
You can Add-Type -TypeDefinition code below and then Update-TypeData as demoed above.
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Text;

public sealed class StreamReaderConverter : PSTypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(object sourceValue, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType != typeof(StreamReader))
        {
            return false;
        }

        object[] args = sourceValue as object[];
        if (args == null || args.Length != 2)
        {
            return false;
        }

        SetBaseObjectIfPSobject(ref args[0]);
        SetBaseObjectIfPSobject(ref args[1]);

        if (args[0] is string && args[1] is Encoding)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public override bool CanConvertTo(object sourceValue, Type destinationType)
    {
        return CanConvertFrom(sourceValue, destinationType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(
        object sourceValue,
        Type destinationType,
        IFormatProvider formatProvider,
        bool ignoreCase)
    {
        object[] args = (object[])sourceValue;
        string path = Path.GetFullPath((string)args[0]);

        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            throw new ItemNotFoundException(string.Format(
                "Cannot find path '{0}' because it does not exist or is not a file.", path));
        }

        return new StreamReader(path, (Encoding) args[1]);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(
        object sourceValue,
        Type destinationType,
        IFormatProvider formatProvider,
        bool ignoreCase)
    {
        return ConvertFrom(
            sourceValue, destinationType, formatProvider, ignoreCase);
    }

    private static void SetBaseObjectIfPSobject(ref object value)
    {
        if (value is PSObject)
        {
            value = ((PSObject)value).BaseObject;
        }
    }
}

